# How can I store an ObjectIndex in my file system so I don't need to recreate it every time with LlamaIndex?

Tags: python, openai-api, llama-index

Starting off by saying that I'm totally new to this, so super thankful for any help I can get!

I have the following code (from one of the SQL examples from LlamaIndex's website)

```
engine = create_engine('url')

sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine)
table_node_mapping = SQLTableNodeMapping(sql_database)
index_text = "Some text describing the table"

table_schema_objs = []

table_schema_objs.append(SQLTableSchema(table_name="table_name", context_str=index_text))

index = ObjectIndex.from_objects(
  table_schema_objs,
  table_node_mapping,
  VectorStoreIndex,
)
```

It works perfectly fine, and I can then use the `SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine` to query the database and get answers. But I want to be able to create the index once so I can reuse it without recreating it every time.

One of the other examples from the website shows how to store the index to a folder like this

```
parser = SimpleNodeParser()
nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)

index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(nodes)

index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="index")
```

I want to do the same thing but with the index I created with `ObjectIndex.from_objects`, but I can't seem to figure out how.

I can of course create another type of index, but from the other examples it seemed like they used text to input to create the index from and not objects.

Comment: Nope, seems like it can't be done with an ObjectIndex at the moment